# react native: Horizontal scrolling gallery

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wan to make a horizontal scrolling gallery in react-native:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqQn1.jpg) where the seperate screens sort of click. I would also like those [little circle things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYyPE.jpg) to show you how many pages there are, and which screen you are on. Like those above the dock on the home screen of ios

---

As of now I just have a horizontal scrollView with some 'cards' in it:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>

                    <View style={{
                        height: 9,
                    }}>
                        {/*buffer between items*/}
                    </View>

                    <View 
                        style={{flexDirection: 'row',
                        width: width-9,
                        height: 50,
                        top: 163,
                        alignContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        //justifyContent: 'flex-wrap',
                        flexWrap: 'wrap'
                        }}
                    >

                        {/*card 1*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('General')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'General Info'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 2*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('Grades')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Gradebook'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 3*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('Grades')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Lunch Menu'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 4*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('BellSchedule')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'Bell Schedules'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                        {/*card 5*/}
                        <Card
                            onPress={() => navigate('About')}
                            source={require('../resources/icons/information.png')}
                            text={'About'}
                        >
                        </Card>

                    </View>

                </ScrollView>
```

What I have now doesn't have 'pages' and has fluid scrolling.
It porbably will be nothing like the solution.
Also what is this of scroll/view/gallery thing called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a view pager component instead that has circle indicators.
Refer [ReactNativeViewPager](https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager)

Code will look like something below

```
 <IndicatorViewPager
   style={{height:200}}
   indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
            <Text>page one</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
            <Text>page two</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
            <Text>page three</Text>
      </View>
  </IndicatorViewPager>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am looking for!